# Как заполнить цвет фона навигационного элемента

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<header class="header" id="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="header__inner">
          <div class="header__logo">
            <div class="header__name">
              <span class="header__name-first">C</span>LEARCUT
            </div>
            <div class="header__after-name">Free PSD Website Template</div>
          </div>

          <nav class="nav" id="nav">
            <a class="nav__link" href="#" data-scroll="#HOME">HOME</a>
            <a class="nav__link" href="#" data-scroll="#STYLE DEMO"
              >STYLE DEMO</a
            >
            <a class="nav__link" href="#" data-scroll="#FULL WIDTH"
              >FULL WIDTH</a
            >
            <a class="nav__link" href="#" data-scroll="#DROPDOWN">DROPDOWN</a>
            <a class="nav__link" href="#" data-scroll="#PORTFOLIO">PORTFOLIO</a>
            <a class="nav__link" href="#" data-scroll="#GALLERY">GALLERY</a>
          </nav>
          <button class="burger" type="button" id="navToggle">
            <span class="burger__item">Menu</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
 
css


@font-face {
  font-family: "Georgia Regular";
  src: url("Georgia.eot");
  src: url("Georgia.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("Georgia.woff") format("woff"), url("Georgia.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  margin: 0;

  font-family: "Georgia", serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6c7279;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

  background-color: #fff;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

/*Container
================*/
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

/* Header
============== */
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-top: 4px solid #a7c353;
}
.header.fixed {
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  background: #31344e;
}

.header.fixed .header__inner {
  padding: 15px 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.header__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* padding: 35px 0; */
  line-height: 1.8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a7c353;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.header__name {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.header__name-first {
  font-size: 35px;
}
.header__after-name {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #979797;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
/* Nav
============== */
.nav {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.nav__link {
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: #979797;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
}
.nav__link:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.nav__link:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #a7c353;
}
```

Comment: верхняя картинка - что у меня, нижняя то что хотелось бы

Comment: .nav - где высота у этого элемента?

Comment: добавил полный код, высота вроде как .header__inner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз у вас в `.header { height:100px }` выставлен.
Тогда просто нужно добавить:

```
.nav__link {
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: да, так! спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить align-items: stretch;

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, добавил, но эффекта не было =\

Comment: @Dmitry видимо обертка в которой находится nav тоже сдерживает его. Ему тоже тогда надо align-items: stretch прописать, либо можно поиграться с line-height для ссылок. Больше кода нужно видеть.

Comment: да, всё так. спасибо!